# I used ityped-npm library and i18next translator. The problem is, I can’t translate the inside of the array. How do I translate words in an array?

Tags: reactjs

[image]
I need to translate the words in the picture into ru ,en...
in english ['Mobil', 'Developer'] , in russian ['Мобильный','разработчик'] the array must take this value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean, but isn't this working?

```
strings: [t('Mobil'), t('Developer')]
```

or something like this: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays#objects

having this in your resources:

```
texts: ['Mobil', 'Developer']
```

and then using it like this:

```
strings: t('texts', { returnObjects: true })
```

Comment: in english ['Mobil', 'Developer'] , in russian ['Мобильный','разработчик'] the array must take this value

Comment: yes, just add it to your translation resources

Comment: if you’re new to react-i18next, have a look at: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb